# Locked steering wheel moved/rotated after replacing struts. Is this okay?

Tags: struts

So I hired a mechanic to replace my front left strut. I parked the car in a lifter and left it with the steering wheel perfectly aligned straight then i turned off the car. When the strut work was done i went back inside the car and noticed that the steering wheel rotated a decent amount to the left from its original position and note that the steering wheel was locked since the car was turned off. Is this normal? Does this cause damage to my steering wheel? Is it still okay to use? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you get an alignment done after the front end work? This is both needed after major front end work as well as it will solve the issue of the steering wheel being off.

Answer (score 0):

The work to replace the strut can easily cause the steering wheel to be moved.

Normally the car would also be given a road test to make sure, so if it is driving correctly and the wheel sits straight when traveling in a straight line then all should be fine.